# Does begin_nested() automatically rollback/commit?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When `begin_nested` is used as a context manager, e.g.

```
with db.session.begin_nested:
    # do something
```

If an `IntegrityError` is thrown, will `db.session.rollback ()` be called automatically? On the contrary, if no exception is thrown, will `db.session.commit()` be automatically called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a transaction, such as one from [`begin_nested`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.begin_nested), is used as a context manager, the transaction is commited at exit, or rolled back if there was an error in the block or during commit.

Here is the relevant source: https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/81518ae2e2bc622f8cd47287a575ad4c0e43ead1/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L558-L569